# What unit of measurement is userAcceleration returned in?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm creating an iOS app that uses the values of `CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration`. That is, the acceleration that the user is giving to the device without gravity.

I'm just wondering, what unit of measurement are the acceleration values returned in? Is it m/s^2, or is it determined by the `deviceMotionUpdateInterval`? I can't find anything about it in the Apple developer docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `G` - 9.81 m/s^2. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmacceleration) of `CMAcceleration` structure

Comment: Ah ok. I think I got confused because the docs said userAcceleration excluded gravity, and for some reason that meant the units wouldn't be in Gs. Should've just clicked through to CMAcceleration. Thanks! :)

Comment: Excluded gravity means that it represents acceleration without the Earth's constant 1G

Comment: Yes, I realise that now. Thank you.